# @angular/forms FormBuilder pops Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

For every instance where I try to reference the value entered into my form I get this funny `Property 'notes' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.` error. The line that this is caused by is `'notes': this.addForm.controls.notes.value`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the whole context of the error

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class TheNewClass {
    addApi(): void {
        if (this.addApiForm.valid) {
            Api.insert({
                'notes': this.addApi.controls.notes.value
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the form in which the values are retrieved from and the method is called.

```
<form [formGroup]="addApiForm" (ngSubmit)="addApi()" class="inline-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apiNotes">Notes</label>
        <input id="apiNotes" formControlName="apiNotes" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Notes">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share some more code ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 sure

Comment: how you have defined `addApi` formGroup which you are accessing inside `TheNewClass` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormControl can be accessed as:

```
'notes': this.addApiForm.controls['notes'].value
```

Comment: that was it...so simple I'll mark as answer when the time limit is up.